# Change output without modifying code

Tags: java

This question was recently asked in an interview that i attended.

```
public class MagicOutput { 
   public static void main(final String argv[]) { 
      System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
   } 
}
```

I was asked to preserve both method main signature (name, number and type of parameters, return type) and implementation (body of method),

and to make this program to output to standard console message `"Magic Output !"`

I took around 2 minutes to answer. My solution was to put a static block there and output the required string.

```
static{
   System.out.println("Magic Output !");
}
```

This does work but , it prints both `Magic Output !` and `Hello, World!`

How can i make it to output only magic string ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
static{
   System.out.println("Magic Output !");
   System.exit(0);
}
```

or funnier (depends on String implementation - works with openjdk 8):

```
static {
  System.out.println("Magic Output!");
  try {
    Field f = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set("Hello, World!", new char[0]);
    f.set(System.lineSeparator(), new char[0]);
  } catch (Exception ignore) { }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer in a short time! I want to up vote 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use static nested classes to achieve that.

```
public class MagicOutput {   
    public static void main(final String argv[]) { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World!"); 
    }   
    static class System {
        static Out out = new Out();
    }
    static class Out {
        void println(String s){
            java.lang.System.out.println("Magic Output !");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect System.out to an instance of PrintStream using System.setOut() on the static block.